# macOS 10.12 brew install openssl issue

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

Trying to install openssl on homebrew using:

```
brew install openssl
```

Is giving the following error during make:

```
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rand/randfile.d.tmp -MT crypto/rand/randfile.o -c -o crypto/rand/randfile.o crypto/rand/randfile.c
In file included from crypto/rand/rand_unix.c:38:
/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h:35:9: error: unknown type name 'CCCryptorStatus'
typedef CCCryptorStatus CCRNGStatus;
        ^
crypto/rand/rand_unix.c:385:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCCSuccess'
    if (CCRandomGenerateBytes(buf, buflen) == kCCSuccess)
                                              ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [crypto/rand/rand_unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
```

Brew is trying to install openssl 1.1.1l:

```
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b6ccc5a2a602c2af3480bbcf1656bd9844595974ba60501871ac12504508e818--openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
```

I need this dependency to install many other applications/tools, e.g., wget or python - and would like to use homebrew to do this.

The brew version I am using is:

```
Homebrew 3.2.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fa395c6627; last commit 2021-08-27)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 606ed52390; last commit 2021-08-27)
```

macOS is: 10.12.6 (Sierra) and I am using a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)

Is there any way I can get around this issue to install openssl? Or anyway I can install python specifying a different openssl to use as a dependency?

I was able to install openssl 1.0 using the following brew command:

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
```

However, python continually tries to use openssl 1.1.1l which is failing with the above error.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same error on my macOS 10.13.6. Try to install gdal dependency, numpy. And it required openssl@1.1

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by editing formula (`brew edit openssl`)
and adding

```
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

to args array in `configure_args`.

As below:

```
  def configure_args
    args = %W[
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --openssldir=#{openssldir}
      no-ssl3
      no-ssl3-method
      no-zlib
      ##### add the line here ####
      -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
    ]
    on_linux do
      args += (ENV.cflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.cppflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.ldflags || "").split
      args << "enable-md2"
    end
    args
  end
```

Comment: This resolved it for me on OS X 10.13 High Sierra.  Thanks!

Comment: where do you add it exaclty, please?

Comment: Great works for me on 10.13 High Sierra. Thanks @Hulkur.

Comment: This also solved my problem.  I did have to configure my brew editor with -- export HOMEBREW_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim" -- added to .zshrc or .bashrc.  After that, 'brew edit openssl' worked.  Find 'configure_args' in the file and add line noted above before the closing bracket (i.e. ])

Comment: $ export EDITOR=nano
$ export VISUAL="$EDITOR"

Comment: Thank you, it's work on my Mac 10.13.6 too. It takes 15 minutes to complete

Comment: I was still getting failures during the 'test' phase of the install. Cured, of course, by commenting out the tests during the `brew edit openssl` task. i.e. ensure `# system "make", "test"` in the 'install' def. openssl@1.1 (1.1.1l) now installs and appears to function - allowing other components that depend on it to also complete their installation.

Comment: Still an issue on Mac OS X 12.4 (Monterey) sad

Answer (score 9):

I had to change the following file on Sierra (MacOs 10.12):

```
sudo chmod a+w /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h

vi /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h
```

I've added the following line before the `typedef` statement:

```
#include "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h"
```

And also followed the advice of @Hulkur - run command:

```
brew edit openssl
```

and added

```
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

to `args` array in `configure_args`.

Comment: This solved the issue for me on MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 3):

Seems a bug of openssl itself. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16487

---

~~What about `export SDKROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk "`?~~

---

Homebrew pre-build packages for some versions of macOS. But it keep dropping this pre-building support for old macOS. On macOS 10.12, you're building `openssl` from the source code and *Xcode command line tool* is needed.

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

Then `brew install openssl` again.

Comment: In my case, I have xcode 9.4 installed but still failed when installing openssl.

Comment: @user97103 Xcode is not a superset of Xcode command line tool. You still need to install Xcode CLT to get related libraries. In this case, it is `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto` that is required.

Comment: I did install clt before adding xcode, because its required by homebrew

Comment: Unfortunately installing xcode command line tools is not the issue - this is already installed.

I also have the path you highlighted above: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto` - however, it seems during make/compilation brew is using the version in `/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h` - is there anyway to force brew to install using the XCode CLT dependency instead?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Mac Sierra 10.13.6 (17G14042)

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

I have updated the openssl

```
brew edit openssl
```

add the line inside def configure_args

```
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
def configure_args 
  args = %W[
    --prefix=#{prefix}
    --openssldir=#{openssldir}
    no-ssl3
    no-ssl3-method
    no-zlib
    -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
  ]
```

Run the below comment after this.

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-install-doc --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" rbenv install 3.0.2
```

Comment: This one solved it for me. Not sure what that last command does but it worked. I used 3.1.0 instead of 3.0.2 though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, to edit the file:

```
$ export EDITOR=nano
$ export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

then

```
brew edit openssl
```

After file open add the line
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

```
 # help debug inevitable breakage.
  def configure_args
    args = %W[
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --openssldir=#{openssldir}
      no-ssl3
      no-ssl3-method
      no-zlib
      -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
    ]
    on_linux do
      args += (ENV.cflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.cppflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.ldflags || "").split
      args << "enable-md2"
    end
    args
  end
```

Save edition and install

```
brew install openssl
```

Notice: the installation took a long time, but it's worked.

Comment: Didn't work for masOS Monterey:
`rvm install "ruby-2.6.5"
...
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/xxx/.rvm/log/1647285213_ruby-2.6.5/make.log
`

Answer (score 1):

This issue has now been resolved (since 9/11/2021) and patches are no longer required

Comment: Not true. The issue persists.

Comment: Why are you saying that? The PRs have been merged and I reverted all of my changes and it works correctly.

Comment: Because I tried this with a fresh installation of the operating system, and I encountered the same issue. The issue may not have been resolved in full, and other answers are still useful, as one of them did resolve my issue.

Comment: The issue https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16487 has been resolved and relevant patches integrated. Are you sure you have the issue describer here?

Comment: I see no new reports of this being an issue from anyone else

Answer (score 0):

After brew edit openssl, I end up with a new error:

```
=> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l --openssldir=/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1 no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method no-zlib -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include darwin64-x86_64-cc enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/francis/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl@1.1/02.make:
include "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h"
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h:35:9: error: expected identifier or '('
include "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h"
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h:52:1: error: unknown type name 'CCRNGStatus'
CCRNGStatus CCRandomGenerateBytes(void *bytes, size_t count)
^
crypto/rand/rand_unix.c:385:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCCSuccess'
    if (CCRandomGenerateBytes(buf, buflen) == kCCSuccess)
                                              ^
4 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [crypto/rand/rand_unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit**

Silly me, I had:

```
include "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h"
```

Instead of

```
#include "CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h"
```

So make sure you have a hash first.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS prior to 10.12 (e.g. 10.11 El Capitan) there is another issue - test failure:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../test/recipes/05-test_rand.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=2,  5 wallclock secs ( 0.38 usr  0.06 sys +  5.71 cusr  2.48 csys =  8.63 CPU)
Result: FAIL
make[1]: *** [_tests] Error 1
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

There is an issue and a pull request for OpenSSL that is open to fix this:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16517

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/16587

If you have this issue go over and vote for them