# install php with brew with highsierra mac os x failure

Tags: php, homebrew

when i try to install php with brew install php with my high sierra i got this error:

```
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/rand/rand_unix.d.tmp -MT crypto/rand/rand_unix.o -c -o crypto/rand/rand_unix.o crypto/rand/rand_unix.c
In file included from crypto/rand/rand_unix.c:38:
/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonRandom.h:35:9: error: unknown type name 'CCCryptorStatus'
typedef CCCryptorStatus CCRNGStatus;
        ^
crypto/rand/rand_unix.c:385:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCCSuccess'
    if (CCRandomGenerateBytes(buf, buflen) == kCCSuccess)
                                              ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [crypto/rand/rand_unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related with the openssl package.

I found the solution here:

[macOS 10.12 brew install openssl issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957915/macos-10-12-brew-install-openssl-issue)

Edit the openssl with the following `brew edit openssl`
and add the line:

```
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

To args array in `configure_args`, as below:

```
  def configure_args
    args = %W[
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --openssldir=#{openssldir}
      no-ssl3
      no-ssl3-method
      no-zlib
      ##### add the line here ####
      -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
    ]
    on_linux do
      args += (ENV.cflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.cppflags || "").split
      args += (ENV.ldflags || "").split
      args << "enable-md2"
    end
    args
  end
```

Then you try again to install the PHP. I installed php@7.4.

```
brew install php@7.4
```